# Unknown function generator

Tags: function-generator

I've found this Function Generator in the deep of school's Lab:

[image]

I wasn't able to find an user guide or any similar document. I'm not sure on how to correctly use it.

For example, I don't know:

1. Which output to use: *Hi, Lo, Gnd* ?
2. What are and how may I use Auxiliary Output?

Any idea? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Looks like someone trying to copy the aesthetic of Wavetek's function generators, but beyond that couldn't tell you anything about it. Do you have a part number?

Comment: No . I can't find any

Comment: Contact the people who calibrated it last (I see stickers on the front) and they might be able to assist.

Comment: Sorry if this is obvious, but if you still need a manual after the answers here, look for a nameplate on the back, bottom etc? If it was my own gear or my lab at work (I am trusted to exercise such judgment), I would open the cover to see if there is something identifying the mfg on the pcb, but please ask permission if it is school's and not "junk status" (e.g. found in back corner with a pile of former-grad-student-crap).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would assume that the output signal is between the Output HI and LO terminals, with the LO terminal being signal ground.  The waveform at that output will be as selected by the Waveform switch, and its level controlled by the Amplitude control.

The Auxilliary outputs will always produce their labelled waveforms, and will not be affected by hte Aplitude control.

The white Ground terminals will connect to the case which should be connected to the AC Safety Ground.

(This is onlyy an educated guess - I've never seen that device.)

Comment: Hi Peter, thanks for your reply. What do you mean exactly for "labelled waveforms"? And how may I use it?

Comment: The Aux jacks have Sine, Pulse and Triangle waveforms shown above the terminals.  The Aux jacks allow you to use any or all waveforms at the same time, but without the Amplitude and Offset controls that the main output will have.  Get an oscilliscope and play around with the thing.

Answer (score 2):

**Function generators** follow a similar form. Perhaps this one follows that form:

- **Hi output** 0.1V to 20V peak-to-peak, with 50 ohm output impedance.
- **Lo output** almost zero to 0.2V peak-to-peak, with 50 ohm output impedance.
- **Auxiliary outputs** fixed amplitude, higher output impedance.

All outputs have the same frequency, set by the main dial.

Hi output and Lo outputs have their amplitude set by a knob. Lo output is more useful to test amplifiers that expect a small input signal. If you load these outputs with a 50 ohm resistor, maximum voltage drops from 20V peak-to-peak to 10V peak-to-peak (or from 0.2V p-p to 0.1V p-p for **Lo output**).

These two outputs usually have an *average voltage* of zero. A **DC offset** knob adds a DC voltage to the AC waveform, so that average voltage can be changed from a negative DC to a positive DC voltage.

Usually, the Auxiliary outputs don't have DC voltage offset applied. The frequency of auxiliary outputs is the same as the main Hi, Lo outputs.

Comment: Thanks. Useful contribution.